# Find the ranges of minimal and maximal gradients on sigmoidal curve in R

Tags: r, gradient, derivative

First, this is my first Stack Overflow question so I apologize for violating and decorum. Second, I realize this will be very trivial but I'm stumped. I'm trying to figure out how to find the minimum and maximum gradients on a sigmoidal curve.

I have a function that generates a vector of y values that form a sigmoidal curve:

```
#function to generate Sigmoid curves - works better with enough Xs to be smooth
genSigmoid = function(a, b, c, theta){ 

    y = c + ((1-c) / (1 + exp(-a*(theta-b))))
    return(y)

}

x<-c(1:100)

y<-genSigmoid(.25, .50, 0, x)

plot(x, y, type="n")

lines(x, y)
```

What I would like to do is find the points along this curve where the gradient is the smallest or zero and the points where the gradient is largest. My ultimate goal is to plot the different sections of this curve with different lines styles according the strength of the gradient along the curve. I can generate these different styles by 'eye-balling' it but it would be nice to have something that can do this more precisely.

Comment: FYI, you don't need `lines` here, just do `plot(x, y, type="l")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using the `grad(...)` function in package `numDeriv`.

```
genSigmoid = function(theta,pars){  
  y <- with(pars,c + ((1-c) / (1 + exp(-a*(theta-b)))))
  return(y)
}
x<-c(1:100)
pars <- list(a=0.25, b=0.50, c=0.0)
y<-genSigmoid(x, pars)
plot(x, y, type="l", ylim=c(0,1), col="blue")

library(numDeriv)
z<-grad(genSigmoid,x,pars=pars)
lines(x,z,col="red")
```

[image]

Here `z` is a vector of the derivative of `genSigmoid(...)` with respect to `theta`.

I redefined your function a bit to make the calling sequence simpler (combined the parameters into a named list, and reversed the order of the arguments).

Plotting segments of the curve with different line styles is a bit trickier:

```
lt <- as.integer(3*(z-min(z))/diff(range(z))+1)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z,lt)
plot(x,y,type="n")
lapply(split(df,df$lt),function(df)with(df,lines(x,y,lty=lt)))
```

[image]

So this creates a vector of line types (1,2,3, or 4) based on the value of the derivative, then splits the data based on line type, and plots the segments.

Comment: 1 second before me... It seems that `diff(y)` will do the job too though

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Yes in OP's case the x are equally spaced, and the function is well behaved. It's not a sigmoidal curve, though.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you! Sorry if I messed up the terminology. It's the equation for an item response theory function, which I just assumed was sigmoid. Nevertheless, thank you so much for this. I tried the `grad()` function but couldn't get it to work - looks like your solution is much, much, much better. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you also for cleaning up my function. I'm just getting into R programming so still learning all the good tricks. Thanks!